# If conditions Multiple - better way - PHP

Tags: php

I have a country dropdown, depending on the database value I would like to show one of the country selected.

The following code works

```
<?php if ($associate_details["country"]=="AU"){ echo "selected";} ?>
```

My question is, Is there a better way to show the country selected without writing so many if conditions?

```
<select style="margin-left:1.5em;" name="associate_country">
<option value="US" >United States of America</option>
<option value="AR">Argentina</option>
<option value="AA">Armenia</option>
<option value="AW">Aruba</option>
<option value="AU" <?php if ($associate_details["country"]=="AU"){ echo "selected";} ?>>Australia</option>
```

Comment: Unless you store countries in array - __no__.

Comment: Are all the values for your options hard coded? Do you have them defined in a database or array anywhere?

Comment: "so many conditions"? I see exactly one... You place all countries in an array and iterate over all entries. That way you need to implement exactly one single condition in total.

Comment: @dukedevil294 hardcoded

Comment: Then yeah like the first commenter wrote, there's no way to setup anything other than what you've started (assuming you need this in PHP) because you only have hard coded values to compare your database value to. If you changed it to pull the country abbreviations from a database then you could loop the array of all those values and compare each to your $associate_details["country"] to determine if it should be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some javascript/jquery to set it after the fact

```
 var country = '<?php echo $associate_details["country"];?>';
 $("select[name='associate_country']").val(country);
```

[JS FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/6qyvz015/)

But if your countries are stored in an array then you can just do this...

```
  $countries = [["name"=>"australia","code"=>"AU"], etc etc];

  echo "<select style='margin-left:1.5em;' name='associate_country'>";
  foreach($countries as $value){
   echo "<option value='".$value['code']."' ";
   if ($associate_details["country"]==$value['code']) { echo "selected" ;};
   echo ">".$value['name']."</option>";
  }
```